# Windows 7 UAC requests escalated to sysadmins?

Tags: windows, windows-7, uac

Is there any way to have users UAC requests listed for admins (or a list of selected users)?

One alternative would be popups on the screen of logged on admins. Another would be listing requests on an interface through polling. For the second alternative to work, users would need to know they should wait when a UAC prompt pops up.

I work in a medium sized company where we need good gontrol over the IT environment. At the same time taking care of every UAC request the users need in their daily work is tedious.
Therefore the functionalit of listing, and approving, the requests based on the sending user and a screenshot would save a lot of time.

A tool that can monitor the users computers for requests and escalate them to admins would be great. Is there such a tool? If not, can it be created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By design Windows 7 can not log UAC requests, but whenever it's starting an UAC prompt it's also launching the consent.exe process - maybe you can find a tool that takes a screenshot automatically when a specific process is launched.

Comment: Maybe an AutoIt script that mostly sits idle in WinWait()?

Comment: Thanks for the headsup, a quick search doesn't find any ready-made tool for that. AutoIT + send screenshot e-mail should do as a test of the idea.